# how to use ftrace to track linux fair (scheduler) process

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler, ftrace

I'm working on a project on CFS.
Using Ftrace to track the whole path of fair process in Linux.

According to documentation 
https://lwn.net/Articles/370423/.

```
[tracing]# echo $$ > set_ftrace_pid
```

I can track the specific process with process pid. But fair process pid isn't static (changes rapidly) so, I'm not able to track it.

I'm new to stack overflow and system programming.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to have a look at [Off-CPU Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/offcpuflamegraphs.html), which show what processes block on and what wakes them up.

[image]